# Share Vue variable across whole Laravel application

Tags: performance, laravel, vue.js, mixins

I am using a mixin to detect mobile users. Now I don't want to import this mixin into every single component where I need it, because this way I think it is probably running multiple times at the same time.

So I tried to do it like this (in app.js):

```
import DetectMobile from './mixins/DetectMobile.vue'
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mixins: [ DetectMobile ],
});
```

But that doesn't work, when I try to access one of the variables from the mixin within a component, I get undefined.

Comment: It would be helpful to see both the contents of `DetectMobile.vue`, as well as how you're trying to access one if it's variables.

Comment: in DetectMobile.vue, I have a data() variable which I am trying to access via this.variablename inside methods of multiple Vue components (all standard Laravel setup)